# Is it possible to set a break point in a Razor template?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, razor, template-engine

Is it possible to set a break point in a Razor template?  One might argue that a template should be so "dumb" or "minimal" in it's logic that you should never have to debug them -- which might be valid.  However, I don't think there is anything in Razor to prevent templates from being abused in some fashion, so eventually a template might need to be dubugged.

Comment: The minimal philosophy is an interesting discussion. I've found that we achieve maximal minimal-ness, in terms of razor code, by using Knockout. However, that introduces the challenges and complexity that come with Knockout. I happen to love Knockout, so that's a no-brainer to me, ymmv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed set a break point in a Razor template. And regardless of the "dumbness" of your view, it will unavoidably, if usefully, populate the view with values which you can debug as needed. Another reason to love you some ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

As long as the debugger is attached to the website, that will just work.